# Getting error '_http_outgoing.js:335' while sending API response from backend to frontend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, get

In my `Angular/Node` application, I am calling a `3rd party API` in the Node.js backend and I am facing an error while sending data to the Angular.js frontend.

Here's the relevant part of my `Node.js` code:

```
app.use('/callApi', function(req, res, next) {

    var result;

    var url = 'http://someApi.com/someData';

    http.get(url, function(resp) {
        var body = '';

        resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
            console.log("Got body: " + body);
        });

        resp.on('end', function() {
            console.log("Got response: " + body);   // WORKS!

            // res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            // res.send(body);                      // DOES NOT WORK!

            sendResult(body);                       // DOES NOT WORK!
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: ", e);
    });

    function sendResult(result){
        res.send(result);
    };

    res.send('about done');                         // WORKS!

    next();
});
```

In the Node.js terminal, I see the response followed by an error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
```

... and the Node.js process gets terminated.

I dont see this `_http_outgoing.js` file anywhere in my project.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: There should be more to the error than just the built-in filename and line number, such as the actual exception message and more stack trace lines. Did you try adding an error handling middleware?

Comment: Also, what version of node are you using?

Comment: @mscdex I wish there was more to that error. How do I add a error handling middleware?  I am using `node v0.12.4`.

Comment: You add one by adding a middleware with 4 parameters: `app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { console.error(err.stack) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW the actual error is [`Can't set headers after they are sent.`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/0a604e92e258c5ee2752d763e50721e35053f135/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L335)

The problem is that you're calling `next()` at the end of your route handler. So some other middleware or route handler is also handling the request and already sending a response before your `http.get()` finishes.

Remove that `next()` and responding to the request from inside the `http.get()` should work fine.